# Silverlight Application throwing Null reference Exception on clearing list which is bound to Grid

Tags: silverlight, grid, infragistics

In Silverlight Application I have bound one ObservableCollection to Grid.

But when I edit row of grid,I am saving updated data in db and clear observable collection of grid and reinsert new values in it.

but when I try to clear observable collection it is throwing an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Am I missing Anything here.

Code:

```
MyList.Clear();
```

> **StackTrace of Exception**
>
> at
>   Infragistics.AutomationPeers.CellsPanelAutomationPeer.Row_PropertyChanged(Object
>   sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)\r\n   at
>   System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)\r\n   at
>   Infragistics.RecyclingContainer`1.OnPropertyChanged(String name)\r\n
>
>   at Infragistics.Controls.Grids.Row.SetSelected(Boolean isSelected)\r\n
>   at
>   Infragistics.Controls.Grids.Row.Infragistics.ISelectableObject.SetSelected(Boolean
>   isSelected)\r\n   at
>   Infragistics.Controls.Grids.SelectedCollectionBase`1.InternalRemoveItemSilently(Int32
>   index)\r\n   at
>   Infragistics.Controls.Grids.SelectedCollectionBase`1.RemoveItem(Int32
>   index)\r\n   at Infragistics.Collections.CollectionBase`1.Remove(T
>   item)\r\n   at
>   Infragistics.Controls.Grids.RowsManager.InvalidateSelectionAndActivation(Boolean
>   validateInList, Boolean invalidateSelection)\r\n   at
>   Infragistics.Controls.Grids.RowsManager.InvalidateItemSource(Boolean
>   invalidateSelection)\r\n   at
>   Infragistics.Controls.Grids.RowsManager.DataManager_CollectionChanged(Object
>   sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)\r\n   at
>   Infragistics.DataManagerBase.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)\r\n   at
>   Infragistics.DataManagerBase.OnDataSourceCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)\r\n   at
>   Infragistics.DataManager`1.OnDataSourceCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)\r\n   at
>   Infragistics.DataManagerBase.DataSource_CollectionChanged(Object
>   sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)\r\n   at
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)\r\n   at
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.ClearItems()\r\n
>   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Clear()\r\n   at

Comment: Have you implemented `OnPropertyChanged` for any of the `properties` in the class whose list is `MyList`?

Comment: Yes I have implemented


     public ObservableCollection<object> MyList
        {
            get
            {
                if (_MyList== null)
                {
                    _MyList= new ObservableCollection<object>();                 }

                return _MyList;
            }
            set
            {
                _MyList= value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(p => p.MyList)
            }
        }

Comment: I have implemented OnPropertyChanged  for collection itself

Comment: In your `OnPropertyChanged` function can you check if handler is null?

    `var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`

Comment: Error is throwing only when I try to clear collection after edit and save...otherwise it works ...I have also refresh button on that same code get execute without exception but when I try to edit  and save after that I am trying to clear and refill that collection but on clear its throwing error